# is it Possible to add CDN in react native?

Tags: react-native, font-awesome

is it possible to add Fontowesome 5 CDN link in react native?

https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/icons/

Answer (score 0):

Not by CND but simply by npm package. It's great and there is a lot more than only FA icons:
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

You can easily browse them here:

https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

Briefly how to use it:

`npm install --save react-native-vector-icons`

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
const myIcon = <Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but i know how to use FontAwesome Icon without it :)

First you have to install react-native-vector-icons first, like this:

```
yarn add react-native-vector-icons
```

OR

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons
```

AND THEN:

```
cd ios
pod install
```

BUT IF your using Android
i dont know how but this is a tutorial:

https://aboutreact.com/react-native-vector-icons/

you can research more if that doesnt help

AND THEN

import it on your js file, like this:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
```

BUT Not only there is FontAwesome5 or FontAwesome... There are others as well... These are all

```
import AIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import EnIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import EvIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import FeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import FAIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import FA5Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import FA5PIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5Pro';
import FouIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Foundation';
import FonIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto';
import IonIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import MIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import MCIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import OIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';
import SIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';
import ZIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Zocial';
```

DONT FORGET TO DO THIS AFTER YOUR IMPORT:

FAIcon.loadFont();

i really recommend using MaterialCommunityIcons

And here is the link for all the icons you can use: https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

Here is the usage of Icon

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import MCIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

MCIcon.loadFont();

export default class Icon extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MCIcon color={'white'} size={30} name={'bell'} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo react native it is very easy, you can use `@expo/vector-icons`

```
import { FontAwesome, FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";

<FontAwesome 
  name="<icon name>"
  color="#000000"
  size={24}
/>
```

you can browse many icons for [expo vector icons](https://icons.expo.fyi/)

**NOTE:** This is only for expo-react-native